# How to upload a folder (recursively) with smbclient?

Tags: linux, samba, smbclient

For the life of me, I can't get the smbclient command to actually transfer any folders.

Since I can't find any documentation anywhere else (the MAN page is not helpful at all), I've been trying to figure this out with more Googling than I can feel comfortable admitting.  [This](https://www.linux-tips.org/article/47/recursively-mput-with-smbclient) is the closest I've been able to find to documentation, but I can't seem to get this method to work.

I'm hoping someone can explain what's going on and how to actually make this work, that would be very appreciated.

```
smb: \> recurse
smb: \> prompt
```

With one of the following:

```
smb: \> mput FolderOfFiles
smb: \> mput FolderOfFiles*
smb: \> mput /home/share/FolderOfFiles
smb: \> mput /home/share/FolderOfFiles*
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recursively download a directory using smbclient?](https://superuser.com/questions/856617/how-do-i-recursively-download-a-directory-using-smbclient)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out based upon the following answer: https://superuser.com/a/856640/380029

In a nutshell, using "mput *" instead of what I used above.

```
mkdir Dest
cd Dest
mput *
```